# R: Exclude submatrix

Tags: r

I would like to retrieve all entries in a matrix that are *not* contained in a submatrix.  For example, given a matrix:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2)
```

I would like to, for example, be able to retrieve `c(2,3,4)`, by retrieving all entries in `A` that are not `A[1,1]`.  `A[-1,-1]` does not do what I want, as it returns only entry `4` (excluding column 1 and row 1).

I couldn't find the answer by looking at the documentation for `?'['` or `?subset`, and I didn't see any answers on the R help list or StackOverflow that dealt with this question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use `outer` like so:

```
A[outer(1:2,1:2, FUN=function(i,j) !(i %in% 1 & j %in% 1))]
```